# Swagger expand on possible endpoints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am currently use Swagger to expose all my endpoints, but these endpoints are currently formatted as:
`/get/{name}, /put/{name}`, where the name can only be those names which I have in database?

Is somehow possible to make swagger expand the general API definition to contain all possible API call one could make, meaning all possible names?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? Are you using Swashbuckle? Most likely you will have to hardcode the possible names in an XML comment. I don't see any way to do this excepted using another tool to update your swagger file after reading from the database...

Comment: I saw I could do this as a middleware? but how about dbcontext and middleware?

Comment: You should be able to add a middleware to the `Configure` method of your `Startup` class. Here you should have access to `IServiceProvider` or other injected dependencies to resolve DbContext (if DbContext has properly been registered in your `ConfigureServices` method).

Comment: not quite sure i understand how you want me to this? @LucasS.

Comment: See my answer, I tried to explain what I meant in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using .NET Core.
I have not tested this solution, but hopefully it is on the right track.

In your `Startup` class, you are probably registering Swagger in the `ConfigureServices` method, as well as your database context.

You need to add one line in `AddSwaggerGen` to register a custom filter.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<YourContext>();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

        // Custom filter (could also be a SchemaFilter)
        c.ParameterFilter<CustomParametersFilter>();
    });
}
```

Here is the `CustomParametersFilter` class:

```cs
public class CustomParametersFilter : IParameterFilter
{
    private readonly YourContext dbContext;

    public CustomParametersFilter(YourContext dbContext)
    {
        // Here you also have access to IServiceProvider or any dependency
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Apply(IParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
    {
        if (parameter.Name == "some_name")
        {
            // Use dbContext to retrieve your values
            List<string> validValues;
            // ...

            parameter.Description = string.Join(", ", validValues);
        }
    }
}
```

The code for `CustomParametersFilter` is a starting point, but it can be adjusted to suit your needs. `IParameter` (and `OpenApiParameter`) offer many more options.

Comment: I am getting Cannot resolve scoped service 'Database.Data.SchemaContext' from root provider.

Comment: Have you registered any implementation of this `SchemaContext` class, in the `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: Yes -  it is registered as you stated above .. The error occur when I call my swagger endpoint swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: `Cannot resolve scoped service 'Database.Data.SchemaContext' from root provider.` is the error I am getting